# Do I really need to have exception handling in this simple RxJava async scenario?

Tags: java, rx-java

I am very new to RxJava, although I'm familiar with streams and somewhat with Javascript promises.  I'm working with some existing code using RxJava, and some comments that some people have made about that code.  I'd like to get more background on this, while I continue to absorb the documentation.

The block in question is this (some names changed):

```
public ShippingMethodHolder callClientsAsync(ShippingMethodContext shippingContext) {
    Single<ShippingMethodResponse> productOneResponseEntity = Single.<ShippingMethodResponse>create(source -> {
        source.onSuccess(getProductOneowShippingMethodResponse(shippingContext));
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

    Single<ShippingMethodResponse> productTwoResponseEntity = Single.<ShippingMethodResponse>create(source -> {
        source.onSuccess(getProductTwoShippingMethodResponse(shippingContext));
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

    Single<ShippingMethodHolder> singleProductCartResponseHolder = Single.zip(productOneResponseEntity, productTwoResponseEntity,
            (dtvResponse, productTwoResponse) -> {
                return new ShippingMethodHolder(dtvResponse, productTwoResponse);
            });
    return singleProductCartResponseHolder.blockingGet();
}
```

The comment made about this code from people more informed about this essentially says that this is missing RxJava exception handling "and will cause blocking or crashing of the stream".  I imagine this refers to the fact that the two async calls have "onSuccess()" calls, but no "onError()" calls.

However, this seems odd to me.  The scope that "onSuccess()" is being called isn't for business logic success or failure, but seemingly on RxJava's attempt to make an asynchronous call.

I could use some advice on whether this is really a problem from RxJava's point of view.

Answer (score 1):

`create` is there mainly to bridge an asynchronous source with the reactive world, but your code seems to call something blockingly just to signal its value. For that, `fromCallable` is more appropriate and communicates the intent to the reader much better:

```java
Single<ShippingMethodResponse> productOneResponseEntity = 
    Single.<ShippingMethodResponse>fromCallable(() -> 
        getProductOneowShippingMethodResponse(shippingContext)
    )
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

Depending on your type of application, blockingly wait for the result may not be desirable, especially if the method is called from the UI thread. You could return the zipped `Single` and keep composing until a final `subscribe()` can be issued.

> The comment made about this code from people more informed about this essentially says that this is missing RxJava exception handling "and will cause blocking or crashing of the stream"

The original `create` and `fromCallable` will catch your exception and will try to signal it to the consumer. In this case, `blockingGet` will rethrow one of the source exceptions on the caller thread and the other (if any) will be routed to the global `RxJavaPlugins.onError` handler. They probably meant that the caller of your method generally doesn't expect it to throw so they may omit a try-catch around it and fail badly at runtime. Resolving it really depends on what kind or error management you intended in the application.

Comment: I could use more clarification of your last paragraph. Are you suggesting that calling "blockingGet" is a different strategy compared to "create" or "fromCallable"?

Comment: I can see that "create" and "fromCallable" are very similar, both in how they can be used and even their implementation. The fact that the javadoc for each of those methods is very different is a bit confusing.

Comment: They are different operators for different purposes, hence the difference in the documentation. `create`/`fromCallable` are the source side and `blockingGet` is on the consumer side, they are two separate sides to consider.